# Limit of the succession $\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}{n\sin(n\pi)}$

Tags: limits

I can't solve this limit. Do you have any ideas of how to solve it?

Comment: Note $\sin(n\pi)=0$ whenever $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Ok but...isn't it an indeterminate form? I mean the whole limit. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Arkillo No. As shown in the above comment, yours is the zero sequence, just written in a "fancy" way.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do apologize for my stupidity (and my bad english). I kept replacing n with infinite.

Comment: @Arkillo now you could go ahead and answer your own question, that's the best way to see whether you got it or if you still need some help

Answer (score 3):

This succession converges to $0$ since each element of it is $0$. In fact, whatever $n$ is, its product with $\sin(n\pi)$ will always be $0$. This is due to the fact that $\sin(n\pi)=0$ whenever $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Sequences converge (or not) to zero. Limits are (or are not) zero. But limits do not converge to anything.